# How to update database in Django via an illegal intermediate state?

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to change some database entries from one legal state to another, but the intermediate (partially updated) state is not legal. As an example, suppose I'm modeling lectures, each of which is made up of several short topics in some order:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    slug = models.TextField(
        help_text='Abbreviated name of lecture.'
    )

class Topic(models.Model):
    slug = models.TextField(
        help_text='Abbreviated name of topic.'
    )

    lecture = models.ForeignKey(
        Lecture,
        help_text='The lecture this topic is part of.'
    )

    order = models.IntegerField(
        help_text='Impose ordering on topics.'
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('lecture', 'order'),)
```

My test case is:

```
class TestTopicOrder(TestCase):

    def test_reordering_topics(self):

        # The lecture these topics are part of.
        lecture = Lecture(title='Test Lecture', slug='lec')
        lecture.save()

        # Two topics 'zero' and 'one' in that order.
        Topic(lecture=lecture, slug='zero', order=0).save()
        Topic(lecture=lecture, slug='one, order=1).save()

        # Try to invert the order.
        t0 = Topic.objects.get(slug='zero')
        t1 = Topic.objects.get(slug='one')
        t0.order = 1
        t1.order = 0
        t0.save()
        t1.save()
```

Essentially, I'm trying to do:

```
t0.order, t1.order = t1.order, t0.order
```

and then save, but whichever modified object I save first will have the same 'order' value as the other entry.  I could delete and re-make, but when it comes time to re-order a dozen topics at once, that'll be a pain.  What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

A dirty dirty solution... you could drop and recreate the restriction on the database using south api:

```
from south.db import db

db.delete_unique('app_lecture', ['lecture', 'order'])
# do your stuff

# then reenable the unique constraint... 
db.create_unique('app_lecture', ['lecture', 'order'])
```